# Is there any video recorder for Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

i am working in Selennium Webdriver2 with IE specific application. i know we can take the screenshots of the execution. similarly, Is there any option to record selenium execution as a video?

Comment: Not anything inherently present in webdriver.  Previously, I've wanted this behaviour, but have since realized that a timely screenshot will help me more than having to go through a video, trying to identify a certain frame.

Comment: There are providers out there like sauce labs or testing bot which record a video and take screenshots of your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://memorynotfound.com/selenium-record-video-junit-java/) API helped me in solving the above problem, this is for your reference guys,

Comment: This is only partially helpful because it will record the screen of the host computer, NOT the screen of the remote control computers

Comment: @gorbysbm Yeah, i do agree with you

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @MirkoSeifert My blog host recently closed down their operations and I didn't take a backup. All my three years of data gone in a sec. Hows cool is that huh ? Time being use this alternative snippet. http://memorynotfound.com/selenium-record-video-junit-java/

Comment: @Karthikeyan Can you please update your answer so other users do not need to read the comments to figure out the correct link? Thanks!

Comment: @MirkoSeifert Done

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in WebDriver.

Sauce uses http://www.ffmpeg.org/ to record video's.  There are other options like https://code.google.com/p/java-remote-control/.

Generally the answer is that if you want to do it, you are going to have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium provides us with the feature to run the automation code/suite and record the output as a video and save it on your system. This video can then be shared with anyone who can see what the automation is doing. First of all, to enable video recording, we need to download some important jars. They are freely available to download from Google. Below are the jars to be downloaded. These are the latest version available, any other version can also be downloaded:

ATUReporter_Selenium_testNG_5.1.1 and ATUTestRecorder_2.1

Complete code can be found here:
https://mytechdevice.com/how-to-record-video-of-automation-output-in-selenium/