# Selenium - run selenium recording using webdriver or RC

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

It is possible to run selenium recording from `webDriver` or rc?

I have a desktop app, where i have button -> 
after click on it i want to open browser (FF) with recording from selenium -> user will do some actions on this browser -> 
and later i want capture recorded actions and convert them to my xml structure.

It is even possible?

Sorry if it is confusing, i hope you understand it correctly.

Or maybe there is a way to run selenium ide from webdriver (eventually java - i used for this command line exec:

```
String command1 = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\"";
String command = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" -chrome \"chrome://selenium-ide/content/\"";
Process child1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't handle desktop actions. For that you need to use different  automation tool like Sikuli. Sikuli script can be written in java and in between selenium code.

You can use Sikuli for desktop actions. It's an image comparator tool

Refer below link:-
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/sikuli-tutorial-part-2/

Download Sikuli from here:-
http://www.sikuli.org/

Now you need to start a recording.. You can record action perform by selenium Webdriver

Refer below:-

http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2013/03/screen-recording-video-of-java-webdiver.html

[Is there any video recorder for Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333829/is-there-any-video-recorder-for-selenium-webdriver)

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: it is not what i meant. I want to start Selenium IDE record from webdriver, open browser for a user and let him do some testcases which later i will capture on webdriver.

Comment: you can't start IDE from webdriver .. you can observe that the broswer instance which is open by webdriver do not have selenium IDE option .. but by sikuli you can start your browser normally and can click on selenium IDE too